# solution folder loses its project references everytime I merge

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

this has been a frustrating ritual for me for a while. Lately, every time I merge my code with code on the server, something mysterious happens to the reference to a particular solution folder. 2 things exactly happen:

1. Folder becomes empty
2. All the project in the folder are now outside of the folder and they stand stray inside the solution

I am pretty sure there is something going wrong when I try to merge the solution file but I am not sure what part of it is going wrong..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you merging the .sln file?

Auto-merge fails pretty frequently on solution files. If you've added a project and at the same time, the solution file was changed on the server, make sure you walk through every change and validate it manually.

Keep in mind that the .sln structure is not obvious. Each project is included at the beginning of the solution file, but this file also has TFS bindings (bindings? I don't remember the exact term) for each project, with respective indexes. If two persons add different projects at the same time, this part quickly become a mess.

Finally, remember to commit often. More often you commit, less painful are the merges.